# How to sort multi-dimensional array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have given an array 'stockPrices[][]' where stockPrices[i] = [day-i, price-i]. Now, I have to sort this array in order of their days.
Like if
stockPrices = [[3,4],[1,2],[7,8],[2,3]]
Then I have to sort it to
stockPrices = [[1, 2],[2, 3],[3, 4],[7, 8]]

I know how to sort this using quick sort, merge sort. But is there any inbuilt function in C++ to sort the array as I need. I know for sorting one dimensional array we have sort(arr, arr+n), but what about multidimensional array?

Comment: Instead of a two-dimensional array, a simple `std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>` and calling `std::sort` will automatically sort the pairs

Comment: [Example using std::pair](https://godbolt.org/z/1E4Pxjd7M).